# Rails 4 query, scoped by condition from has many through attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, has-many-through

The question is : "**given a company**, how should I build the query that returns **all events** created by all employees **during their respective employments periods** ?"

Ex:

```
@company = Company.create

# Welcome John
@john = User.create
@event_a = @john.events.create date: Date.new(2013,6,1)
@event_b = @john.events.create date: Date.new(2014,1,1)
@company.employments.create user:@john, since: Date.new(2013,12,20)

# Welcome Jack
@jack = User.create
@event_c = @jack.events.create date: Date.new(2012,1,1)
@event_d = @jack.events.create date: Date.new(2013,1,1)
@company.employments.create user:@jack, 
    since: Date.new(2011,12,20), till:  Date.new(2012,12,31)

@company.events
=> [@event_b, @event_c]
# @event_a is not returned because it was created prior to John's hiring
# @event_d is not returned because it was created after Jack's departure
```

I came up with a solution but I would like to know if there are any ways to improve it.

```
class Event
  belongs_to :user

  # attributes
  # date: datetime
  # …
end

class Employment
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :event

  # attributes
  # since: date
  # till: date
  # …
end

class Company
  has_many :employments

  def events
    Event.where employments.map do |e|
      if e.since && e.till
        "(user_id = '#{e.user_id}' AND date BETWEEN '#{e.since}' AND '#{e.till}')"
      elsif !e.since.nil?
        "(user_id = '#{e.user_id}' AND date > '#{e.since}')"
      else
        "(user_id = '#{e.user_id}')"
      end
    end.join(' OR ')
  end
end
```

Do you see any other way to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Events.joins(user: :employments).where(company_id: id)I believe you could use something like this:

```
def events
    Event.where employments.map do |e|
        user=User.find(e.user_id)
        since = e.since
        till  = e.till || Date.parse('3100-12-31') # a day in the distant future if nil
        user.events.where('(date is null) or (date > ? and date < ?)', since, till)
    end
end
```

2nd try, after using the appropriate joins to connect Event and Employment model, you can use the final `where` clause to implement your filter.

The full method, after you've added the right set of joins and filters (thanks), is as follows.

```
def events
    Events.joins(user: :employments).where(company_id: id). # <-This comes from the author, not me.
           where('employments.since is null OR 
                 (employments.since < events.date AND employments.till is null) OR
                 (employments.since < events.date AND employments.till > events.date)')

end
```

Comment: This returns events for a given user. What I want is events for all users of the company while they were employees.

Comment: You should put this inside the map block... I've put the "e" for you... Let me rebuild the answer

Comment: Oh, sorry, you need something different from this... If it's all the same, tell me I can delete my answer.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer, I appreciate the effort. I see 4 issues with your answer. a) it doesn't work :) map will return an array of ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation, but it can work with minor changes: 'Event.find … since, till).pluck(:id)' b) it loads everything in memory, c) it queries the database multiple times (depending on the number of users), which could be avoided by using employments.includes(:user) and using e.user instead of user=User.find, d) I don't like to rely on a random date, however unlikely it is that the codebase survives a thousand years :)

Comment: @user229688, I've added a 2nd alternative with two sql queries, loading only events.*... Give it a look..

Comment: interesting! But, event belongs to user, not employment, and just Employment.joins(user: :events).select("events.*") still returns employments, not events. Nevertheless, you lead me to the answer. You don't need the first line, and for the second I used Events.joins(user: :employments).where(company_id: id) instead. Update your answer and I'll accept it, since what I was looking for was in fact your second where clause. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> how can I query all events created by all employees during their
>   employment for a given company

You *may* wish to use an [`ActiveRecord Association Extension`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-extensions), which basically appends a new method to your association, allowing you to define filtration or some other specifications:

```
#app/models/company.rb
Class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :employments
   has_many :events do
       def by_date(since, till)
           ... logic here
       end
   end
end
```

This will allow you to call:

```
#app/controllers/events_controller.rb
Class EventsController < ApplicationController
    def action
        company = Company.find params[:id]
        @events = company.events.by_date("01-01-2014", "04-01-2014")
    end
end
```

If you let me know in the comments, I'll have a go at populating the method for you

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. This is not exactly what I'm trying to do. The start/end dates vary from one employee to the next, I'll add an example.